# how to install etcher on xubuntu 16.04.4 please?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, etcher

I want to install etcher on Xubuntu 16.04.4,it is not in Xubuntu repositories,I want to write to an SD card to install xubuntu on Raspberry PI 2

Comment: See [Etcher Documentataion](https://github.com/resin-io/etcher#installers)

Answer (score 1):

Etcher is provided as as AppImage. Download Etcher from https://etcher.io/ and unzip it. Now you can directly start the Etcher AppImage.

At first start it asks you if you want to create a desktop file. This is not mandatory but quite useful if you want to start it from your Ubuntu launcher. If you select "No", it will ask you next start again, so you can try Etcher without creating a desktop file immediately.